# .exe file made in MATLAB doesn't run in Server via Task Scheduler

Tags: matlab

I have created a standalone application in MATLAB and I want to run it in schedule in a windows server. However when I create the task in task scheduler the .exe file doesn't run at all.(I have selected to run only when user is logged on) In PC clients runs ok but in server not. Also the app doesn't run either when I am clicking at it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Run from a dos prompt and see what error is thrown

Comment: the error I get is : error using database.jdbc.connection/runsqlscript eerror while executing the SQL script:csv_query.sql (the system cannot find the file specified)